# svnadmin load - E160013 File not found

Tags: svn

I have a subversion that doesn't follow StdLayout (no trunk, tags, branches, just the project files). Now I want to change it like if all existing files would reside below "trunk".

I dumped the repo (svnadmin dump repo > repo.dump) and tried to load it, however there's an error:

```
svnadmin create repo2
svnadmin load repo2 --parent-dir trunk < repo.dump

<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
     * editing path : trunk/text.txt ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '0-0', path '/trunk/text.txt'
```

So what's wrong? How can I fix it? Or is there another way to cleanly move my files? svn version is 1.9.7

Comment: what command was used to create the dump?

Comment: Maybe `svn mkdir trunk && svn mv * trunk && svn commit`?

Comment: @happytimeharry: svnadmin dump repo

Comment: @uzsolt: I tried this, but it truncates history (svn log) as long as I stay inside trunk

Comment: Hmm - it seems I have to create the new parent-dir in the repo before svnadmin load, which then succeeds. It's strange, however, that this is not documented.

Comment: @JeffRSon: the svn move command does not truncate the history. But e.g. in TortoiseSVN you need to uncheck "Stop on copy/rename" to see full history.

Comment: @royalTS: the checkmark is not set and it still stops where I created "trunk".  Yes, I believe this may have been otherwise, but for now even "svn log" stops at that revision :-(

Comment: @JeffRSon only on loading your dump or on svn move too?

Comment: @royalTS: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're referring to. "file not found" comes when loading the dump, svn move works fine but causes "handling" problems later on.

Comment: @JeffRSon which handlings problems? The one with the history (not history before move)? Because svn move will not "break" the history.

Comment: @royalTS - it's a matter of interpretation. Sure, the history of the whole repository is kept: If it is checked out as a whole (contains /trunk as a folder) "svn log" will list all revisions down to 1. However when I check out /trunk, for example, "svn log" shows history just back until where /trunk was created. This is, at least, what I can see. Also, when I would go back to a revision before this point in time all the files would return to where they've been. So, for me, dump/load is the "clean" solution.